# How to add a font in csImageFile

Tags: asp-classic, fonts

Does anyone have experience in using csImageFile by ChestySoft?  I'm left using it as it is part of a site I have taken over.

I'm trying to add a temporary font using the 'AddFont' command but am getting nowwhere with it.  It's only vaguely referred to in the manual.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **TextFont** property to name of font which you just added using **AddFont** method.

```vb
Set Image = Server.CreateObject("csImage...")
    Image.NewImage 500, 500, "#ffffff"
    If Image.AddFont(Server.MapPath("myfont.ttf")) Then 'addfont returns true if success
        ' Adding font successful
    Else ' Could not be added font file
        Err.Raise 8, "csImageFile.AddFont", "File not exists or it's not a valid font file"
    End If
    Image.TextSize = 20
    Image.TextFont = "My Font Name"
    Image.Text 5, 5, "Hey!" 'x=5, y=5
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    Response.BinaryWrite Image.JPGData ' write image directly
```

If you're not sure what the font name, **FontNames** property give you a quick overview. It returns a collection of all the fonts installed (or added by you) on the server.

```vb
For Each fontName In Image.FontNames
    Response.Write fontName & "<br />"
Next
```